# PHP Inherited methods not running

Tags: php, inheritance, methods, parent

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
interface IReportGenerator {

    public function setTitle ($title);

    public function setColumns ($columns);

    public function setPrintArea ($start, $stop);

    public function setPageOrientation ($value);

    public function createReport ($data);

    public function saveReport ($name, $path = null);

    public function saveReportAs ($name, $path = null, $type = null);
}

abstract class AbstractReportGenerator implements IReportGenerator {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->report = new PHPExcel();
    }

    public function setTitle ($title, $now = false) {
        // store

        return $this;
    }

    public function setColumns ($columns) {
        // store

        return $this;
    }


    public function setPaperSize ($value, $now = false) {
        // store

        return $this;
    }

    public function setPageOrientation ($value, $now = false) {
        // store

        return $this;
    }

    public function setPrintArea ($start, $stop, $now = false) {
        // store

        return $this;
    }

    public function saveReport ($name, $path = NULL) {
        return $this->saveReportAs($name,$path,self::EXCEL_2007);
    }

    public function saveReportAs ($name, $path = NULL, $type = NULL) {
        // save report

        return $this;
    }

    public function createReport ($data) {
        $this->doHeader();

        $this->doTitle();

        $this->doColumnHeaders();

        $this->doData($data);

        $this->doFooter();

        $this->doFormatting();

        $this->doMargins();

        $this->doPrintOptions();
    }

    abstract protected function doHeader();

    abstract protected function doTitle();

    abstract protected function doColumnHeaders();

    abstract protected function doData($data);

    abstract protected function doFooter();

    abstract protected function doFormatting();

    abstract protected function doMargins();

    abstract protected function doPrintOptions();
}

class ReportGeneratorSimple extends AbstractReportGenerator {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function doHeader () {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected function doTitle () {
        echo 'title A';
    }

    protected function doColumnHeaders () {
        echo 'column A';
    }

    protected function doData ($data) {
        echo 'data A';
    }

    protected function doFooter () {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected function doFormatting () {
        echo 'format A';
    }

    protected function doMargins () {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected function doPrintOptions () {
        // do nothing
    }
}

class ReportGeneratorFormatted extends ReportGeneratorSimple {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function doHeader () {
        parent::doHeader();
    }

    protected function doFooter () {
        parent::doFooter();
    }

    protected function doFormatting () {
        parent::doFormatting();

        echo 'format B';
    }
}
```

When I do:

```
$report = new ReportGeneratorFormatted();
$report->setTitle('title');
$report->setColumns($columns);
$report->createReport($data);
$report->saveReport('file.xlsx');
```

The output i get is (in no particular order):

```
'data A'
'format A'
```

Any idea why 'title A', 'columns A', and 'format B' are not printing? The saveReport() and saveReportAs() methods are working as well.

Comment: The result is `title Acolumn Adata Aformat Aformat B` and 2 notices about undefined variables

Comment: I have to agree with zerkms: the output is correctly showing for all methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zerkins - You are correct, the code I supplied runs as expected. The results I supplied came from the production code, not the sample.

Given that the sample worked correctly, it was as simple as tracking down the difference in the production code. It turned out to be a missing call to "parent" in one of the child classes.

Thanks!